# Upgraded SASS using @import. It no longer reads my main style sheet

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I'm working on an upgrade to our SASS. I'm using a main "sass" sheet that imports everything else. When I modify an imported file it doesn't compile it. It doesn't even seem to read the @imported files. When I modify the main sheet it compiles just fine.

Gulp Version: 4.0.2
SASS Version: 4.1.0

My gulp file:

```
const gulp = require('gulp')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')
const clean = require('gulp-clean-css')
const rename = require('gulp-rename')
const concat = require('gulp-concat')
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify')
const prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer')
const sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');


var sassSourcesMain = '../scss/source-main.scss';

function style() {
    return (
        gulp
        .src(sassSourcesMain)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass())
        .on('error', sass.logError)
        .pipe(prefixer())
        .pipe(clean())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../min'))
    );
}


function watch(){
    gulp.watch(sassSourcesMain, style)
}

exports.watch = watch
exports.style = style;
exports.default = watch;
```

My main style sheet where everything is getting imported from:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

@import "base/colors";
@import "base/variables";
@import "base/animations";
@import "base/resets";
@import "base/type";
@import "base/homepagebanners";
```

And so forth.

Comment: Why did you comment out the line that watches the other files? With your code, it's only compiling the main sass because that's what you're telling it to do `var sassSourcesMain = '../scss/source-main.scss';`

Comment: When I use that line I get all sort of errors saying other files can't find variables that should be imported from the line above: source-main.scss

Comment: Then you should do some debugging to see why those variables can't be found. It could be an `@import` order issue.

Comment: My issue is that it doesn't even read the @imported files. When I edited base/colors it doesn't recompile or notice the changes.

Comment: If you compile only the `source-main.scss` file and look at the CSS, are the imported styles included?

Comment: Oh!  Yeah it is. Thank you for pointing that out! What I really need though is how to get the terminal to recompile on any changes to those files.

Comment: Right, so we know your `@imports` are being included. Can you update the question with the exact error you're getting if you use the commented out line instead - so comment out the one you have currently that only looks at the `source-main`

Comment: Yeah but i just figured out. I needed to watch the sub folders.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the sub folders into my watch function:

```
function watch() {
    gulp.watch(paths.styles.src, style);
    gulp.watch(subscssfiles, style);
}
```